# assist with creating a modal pop up

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I am currently working on UI that would check the http status for 404 and then pop up a modal that would give instuctions on what to do.

This is my code:
sign-form.component.html

```
<div class="modal">
        <pal-modal>
            <div slot="header">
                <h3>Penny Product</h3>
            </div>
            <div slot="body">
                This product is no longer eligible for sale. Remove the product from the salesfloor.</div>
            <div slot="footer">
                <pal-button type="secondary" size="small"> Close </pal-button>
            </div>
        </pal-modal>

    </div>
```

This is my sign-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Sign }    from '../sign';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {error} from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import {tryCatch} from 'rxjs/internal-compatibility';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-form.component.scss']
})
export class SignFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.getStoreNumber()
  }

  submitted = false;

  model = new Sign('', '');

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getStoreNumber() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(
        (params: ParamMap) => {
          this.model.store = params.get('store');
        }
    )
  }

  getSign() {
    this.submitted = true;
    const sign = this.model;

    const STORE_REGEXP = /^-?\d{3,4}$/;
    const PRODUCTID_REGEXP = /^[-0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;

    if (!sign.store
        || !sign.productId
        || !STORE_REGEXP.test( sign.store )
        || !PRODUCTID_REGEXP.test( sign.productId )) {
      return;
    }

    const store = sign.store.length === 3 ? '0' + sign.store : sign.store;
    let productId = sign.productId.toUpperCase();
    const SKU_REGEXP = /^[-0-9]+$/;
    let productType;
    if (SKU_REGEXP.test( productId )) {
      productType = 'sku';
      productId = productId.split( '-' ).join( '' );
    } else {
      productType = 'model';
    }


    const url = environment.digitalSignageServiceUri + '/ESL/pdf/store/' + store + '/' + productType + '/' + productId;




    window.open(url, '', '');
  }

}
```

can someone guide me on this?  i really just want to write code to make sure the modal popup is styled correctly before moving on to check for http status.  I have tired different things but just can't seem to get it to pop up.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using a mat-dialog component. As it gives you everything you need to show a pop up and you can just concentrate on the actual business logic.
Please follow my stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-kfdktu

Kindly consider accepting the answer if it helps :)